# tomcat8 concurrent limit configuration not working

Tags: java, tomcat, concurrency

I set my tomcat `server.xml` like this:

```
<Connector acceptCount="1" maxThreads="1" maxConnections="1" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

then I use `jemeter` test my web-app(just sleep 3 seconds in logic) with 20 threads(0 Ramp-Up Priod), but no request has been rejected, they are success one by one?

please help me.

thanks

Comment: `they are success one by one`, that is to expect, isn't it ? The client tipically has a timeout while try to connect. I guess your client threads timeout is >=60 s.

Comment: In fact，my expect is some request has been rejected， but they both success， and how to set clinet thread timeout？ the client（jemeter） and server(tomcat in eclipse) in my local machine.

Comment: @PeterMmm Will it? I read the document about [acceptCount](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html) and it said `Any requests received when the queue is full will be refused.`. IMO, if all the requests happened at the same time, the request coming as the 3rd one should be refused. Am I wrong?

Comment: yes,it's my doubts too, I check some other question similar this,  some answer refer to "/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_synack_retries", but i don't know what's this...

Comment: I guess (really don't know for shure) even the connection is refused, the http client thread retries to connect. The client can't know what is going on, while doesn't get any http response (code). So I guess the client will continue to try, depending on the clients connection configuration.

Comment: @PeterMmm I found a post [here](https://coderanch.com/t/647733/Tomcat-BIO-connector-configurations) which seems to be interesting and related to this question.

Comment: oh,thx,I fix it, as you said, this issue due to client timeout seeting, when change 'response' to 500(millseconds) in jemeter, the test show me expected results. it's my first ask in stackoverflow and my english is poor,but you help me fix issue, thank you very much!